# Eclipse Mars - Web Application - Tomcat - Maven - Deploy and Debug

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, tomcat, jakarta-ee

Is there a foolproof simple method to run and debug a Simple (tutorial level) Maven Web App in a local apache tomacat server from Eclipse Mars?.

I am developing a web app and I am able to run it sometimes, and sometimes not, and I am able to debug it sometimes, and sometimes not. Its a bit frustrating.

My current preference is to run the project from a Maven configuration having as goal `tomcat:run`. It builds and runs always, but it wont debug, i.e. if I place a breakpoint within my Java code in the servlet code, it is not reached. (some times it is reached the first time I run the project, but then it fails to find the source code of some file, and stops breaking for the subsequent runs...)

I have tried also "Debug on Server" configuration, but then, in that case I had to run a Maven install before running the project or, otherwise, some classes would not be found. And that also stopped working now. It just cant find some of the classes from src, although the Web Deployment Assembly configuration has the source being deployed into WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: please dont down vote the question without commenting the reason

Comment: the reason might be related to the fact that some dependencies are being injected by Spring, so there is not explicit reference within the code to some classes. Maybe because of this, these classes are not being deployed by eclipse...

Comment: one additional "discovery" is that if I start from scracth, deleting the .metadata folder, and i DONT run Maven clean or install, the "Run in Server" and "Debug on server" works both. After runing Maven, these stop working as they cant find the classes from src folder

Answer (score 1):

(you may have been downvoted because there are a few questions lumped in to one. I'll try to answer them all because I'm all too familiar with your pain)

Eclipse's maven integration is notoriously flaky when it comes to debugging webapps, even with MARS. You can indeed use tomcat6:run or tomcat7:run for webapps. Here's a few 'best practices' that keep me sane:

- Always execute 'clean' as part of the goal.
- Make sure you follow the standard maven WAR project layout. You can break from this but have to be careful to specify all the overridden paths for META-INF etc.
- When you stop/kill the process in Eclipse, you will often find that the process actually continues running but has detached itself from eclipse.exe as a parent process. You need to manually kill the java.exe process or you'll find 'port already in use' errors. ProcessExplorer is very useful for keeping an eye on this.
- When you hit a breakpoint and it says 'source not found', there are a few things you can try.

  - Add your maven installation under window-preferences - maven/installations. Set this as the default one.
  - In your run configuration, make sure that you are using your system installation instead of the embedded one.
  - When you hit a breakpoint, close the editor and then reopen it by clicking on the point in the debug tree.

Comment: Thanks, to solve the "source not found" I switched to the external Maven installation instead of the embedded one and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to debug a maven project with goal "tomcat:run" in Eclipse and the application is breaking at the breakpoints set but you are getting "Source not found" error.

[image]

Follow the below steps to fix this:

1. Go to your debug configuration
2. In the Main tab, make sure you have "Resolve Workspace artifacts" checked
3. Make sure the Base Directory is set as your maven project
4. In the Source tab, make sure you have added your project as a "Java Project" or "Workspace" or "Project"

Step 4 is important, Add -> Java Project/Project and select your project